# How to set a variable in sql and use it in select query to display and perform actions (MAX MIN) on that variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Below is the MySQL query i am trying to run. So basically I need to set a variable for difference between current date and last visited. And that variable I need to use the variable in 2nd query to display it or perform actions such as MAX(@last_visited) or MIN(@last_visited), etc.

```
SET @last_visited = (SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MAX(date_time)) AS last_visited FROM bs_orders GROUP BY user_phone ORDER BY user_phone);

SELECT
    user_phone, @last_visited
FROM
    bs_orders
GROUP BY
    user_phone
ORDER BY 
    user_phone
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Sample data and desired results would make it clear what you are trying to do.  The `SET` is just totally confusing.  You can't set a single value to the results of a query that returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a variable, just calculate it on the fly:

```
SELECT
    user_phone, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MAX(date_time)) as lastvisited
FROM
    bs_orders
GROUP BY
    user_phone
ORDER BY 
    user_phone
```

if you want you can create a variable with the current timestamp before running the query so the query use the same time for all rows.

Also as said in comments you can create a temp table and use it in further queries:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lastvisited(

    SELECT
        user_phone, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MAX(date_time)) as lastvisited
    FROM
        bs_orders
    GROUP BY
        user_phone
    ORDER BY 
        user_phone
);
```

Second query example:

```
Select * 
from TableT T
left join lastvisited L on L.user_phone=T.user_phone
```

Comment: I tried MAX(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MAX(date_time))) in the same code, but it is not working.

Comment: is it giving an error or not giving you the results you want?

Comment: SELECT
 user_phone, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MAX(date_time)) AS last_visited, MAX(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MAX(date_time)))
FROM
 bs_orders
GROUP BY
 user_phone
ORDER BY 
 user_phone

I tried this code, but it is giving me error as follows:
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: the query I put in the answer should give you "time since last visit" really. If you need strictly last visit then max(date_time) should suffice.

Comment: please try the query I posted; the max function is only needed inside the datediff function

Comment: So the thing is that i need to do rfm analysis. So I have to calculate which is maximum difference between current date and last visited. And then do further computations.
i.e I need maximum of this DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), MAX(date_time))

Comment: so instead of SET a scalar variable you probably need a temp table or subquery. The query I posted should be that subquery, since it will give you for every user_phone the diff between current timestamp and last visit.

Comment: Can you please send an example query?

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Thank you so much, I had question,
Rather than making an another table, what if we create a view? Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Yes, of course, that's up to you, if you are going to use this table in the future for other queries a view is a good idea